# how add a zero to the beginning of the numbers in VSTO VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm going to add a zero to the beginning of the numbers. I wrote the following commands, but it is not responding, unfortunately :(

```
    For Each icell In Rng
        icell.Value = "0" & icell.Value
    Next
```

Is it possible to guide me? thank you

```
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range
    Dim icell As Excel.Range

    Rng = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.InputBox("Select a Range",,,,,,, 8)

    For Each icell In Rng
        icell.Value = "0" & icell.Value
    Next`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim Rng As Excel.Range
Dim icell As Excel.Range
Rng = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.InputBox("Select a Range",,,,,,, 8)
For Each icell In Rng
  icell.Value = icell.Value.PadLeft(2, '0')
Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(